# Cannot resolve symbol WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I try created Basic Auth in my java app. For they i used this dependencies in gradle file

```
dependencies {
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter', version: '1.5.9.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '1.5.9.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-parent', version: '1.3.3.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-log4j2', version: '1.4.3.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb', version: '1.5.9.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.7'
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.7'
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-web', version: '2.7'
compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-core')    
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
```

}

When i implementation extend class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter idea show error **Cannot resolve symbol WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** and highlights code red color.
[image]

I tryed also use next dependecies

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-security-core', version: '5.0.0.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-security-web', version: '5.0.0.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-security-config', version: '5.0.0.RELEASE'
```

What dependecies need to be gradle file for the implementation extended class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter?

Comment: It's seems like something wrong with your IDEA, have you tried File -> Invalidate Caches ... -> Invalidate and Restart? Or try add import by yourself and build gradle from terminal

Answer (score 4):

That class will be in group [`org.springframework.security`](https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/blob/81ca49e14968368196472a822eed506f19b27fdc/samples/bearer-token-filter-chain/build.gradle?ts=4#L35) and not *org.springframework.boot* under the artifact `spring-security-config`

```
compile group: "org.springframework.security", name: "spring-security-config", version: "$springSecurityVersion"
```

Although, as the comment suggests,

as sample build.gradle could look like

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"

dependencies {

    compile group: "org.springframework.security", name: "spring-security-core", version: "$springSecurityVersion"
    compile group: "org.springframework.security", name: "spring-security-config", version: "$springSecurityVersion"
    compile group: "org.springframework.security", name: "spring-security-web", version: "$springSecurityVersion"
    compile group: "org.springframework.security", name: "spring-security-oauth2-jose", version: "$springSecurityVersion"
    compile group: "org.springframework.security", name: "spring-security-oauth2-resource-server", version: "$springSecurityVersion"
    compile group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-web", version: "$springBootVersion"
    compile group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-security", version: "$springBootVersion"
    compile group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf", version: "$springBootVersion"
    compile group: "org.thymeleaf.extras", name: "thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5", version: "$thymeleafExtrasSpringSecurityVersion"

    testCompile group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-test", version: "$springBootVersion"
    testCompile group: "org.springframework.security", name: "spring-security-test", version: "$springSecurityVersion"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Refer to https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter.

I believe `websecurityconfigureradapter` is already removed in the latest spring boot library.

Answer (score 1):

try annotating with `@EnableWebSecurity` at the class level before extending the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

```
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
```

Answer (score -3):

In case of SpringBoot, this happens because of SpringBoot not supporting WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in latest version, see here in detail https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter.

To solve this you can change the version of your spring boot from pom.xml like:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

This may work fine :)