# Spring doesn't see WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to create WebSecurityConfig class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, but I always get error "Cannot resolve symbol 'WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter'".
I have already tried to add different dependencies. It's my gradle file

```
dependencies {
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    implementation group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.5.1'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '3.0.0'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-rest', version: '3.0.0'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat', version: '3.0.0'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '3.0.0'
    implementation group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt-api', version: '0.11.5'
    implementation group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.5.1'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-validation', version: '3.0.0'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-core', version: '6.0.0'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-config', version: '6.0.0'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-web', version: '6.0.0'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-oauth2-jose', version: '6.0.0'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-oauth2-resource-server', version: '6.0.0'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version: '3.0.0'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf', version: '3.0.0'
    implementation group: 'org.thymeleaf.extras', name: 'thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5', version: '3.1.0.RELEASE'
}
```

Maybe I don't understand something easy. Can you help me with this,please.
I have already spent 2 days on this

There is the same question on stack overflow ([Cannot resolve symbol WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54177651/cannot-resolve-symbol-websecurityconfigureradapter)), but it doesn't help me.
It's my file with WebSecurityConfig class

```
import nsu.project.springserver.security.jwt.AuthEntryPointJwt;
import nsu.project.springserver.security.jwt.AuthTokenFilter;
import nsu.project.springserver.security.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
....
}
```

Comment: That was deprecated in Spring Security 5.6 and removed in Spring Security 6, hence not available anymore. Check the documentation. Also (unrelated) your dependencies are a bit of a mess, clean them up. You are also using some wrong dependencies (thymeleaf spring scurity 5 should be for security 6).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Video from Dan Vega:

[What's new in Spring Security 6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDOHbK39Oxg&list=PLYjyDlouoSEfFogsLh2Y-9KLzJ1xCq078&index=13)

Spring Security: Upgrading the Deprecated `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`
Configure HTTP Security
More importantly, if we want to avoid deprecation for HTTP security, we can create a `SecurityFilterChain` bean.

For example, suppose we want to secure the endpoints depending on the roles, and leave an anonymous entry point only for login. We'll also restrict any delete request to an admin role. We'll use Basic Authentication:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf()
      .disable()
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE)
      .hasRole("ADMIN")
      .antMatchers("/admin/**")
      .hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
      .antMatchers("/user/**")
      .hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
      .antMatchers("/login/**")
      .anonymous()
      .anyRequest()
      .authenticated()
      .and()
      .httpBasic()
      .and()
      .sessionManagement()
      .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    return http.build();
}
```

The HTTP security will build a `DefaultSecurityFilterChain` object to load request matchers and filters.
[spring Security: Upgrading the Deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-deprecated-websecurityconfigureradapter)

Answer (score 5):

WebsecurityConfigurerAdapter was removed in Spring-boot 3.

Expose a `SecurityFilterChain` bean instead (`SecurityWebFilterChain` if your app is reactive).

Open [the manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/migration/index.html) or have look at [those tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials).